# Comments from facebook on my site

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in facebook stuff so I need your help. I'm looking for a script that grabs facebook comments by date. All I've found on the internet were some plugins, but nothig reliable. I want to see a page with some healty PHP code. I've seen that the comment object has the "created_time" field, but I can't understand how do I get there. Please, any help would be excelent. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Hope it helps.

To get comments which are here
http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola/posts/10150231752583306

go to this link

https://graph.facebook.com/10150231752583306/comments

to retreive 200 of them, you can use limit

https://graph.facebook.com/10150231752583306/comments?limit=200

Comment: thank's, but I've seen that. I still can't understand it. What url should I access to get the last comments from my page?